# Are named arguments part of a method's signature? How and why?

Tags: c#, function, syntax, parameters, arguments

I mean, named arguments seems to be a signature in some way: you cannot call a named method using any name and only respecting parameter's positions. However, we cannot create two methods with the same signatures and names, but using different parameters' names.

Can interfaces force a class' methods to use given parameter's names?

Using named arguments:

> int i = Function(NamedArgument: x);

Not using named arguments:

> int i = Function(x);

Comment: This question is very confusing. Not really sure what you're *really* asking...

Comment: Sorry, my English is limited. I put some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter names aren't part of the signature in terms of the uniqueness constraints, no.

From section 3.6 of the C# 4 spec:

> The signature of a method consists of the name of the method, the number of type parameters and the type and kind (value, reference, or output) of each of its formal parameters, considered in the order left to right. For these purposes, any type parameter of the method that occurs in the type of a formal parameter is identified not by its name, but by its ordinal position in the type argument list of the method. The signature of a method specifically does not include the return type, the params modifier that may be specified for the right-most parameter, nor the optional type parameter constraints.

The parameter names *are* part of what the compiler "knows" about the method though; it's information which *has* to be propagated in the metadata, as it's used for named arguments.

> Can interfaces force a class' methods to use given parameter's names?

No. Indeed, you can cause some really confusing code:

```
interface IFoo
{
    public int M(int x, int y);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int M(int y, int x)
    {
        return x - y;
    }
}

...

Foo foo = new Foo();
IFoo ifoo = foo;
Console.WriteLine(foo.M(x: 10, y: 3)); // Prints 7
Console.WriteLine(ifoo.M(x: 10, y: 3)); // Prints -7
```

Comment: Oh my God, you are Jon Skeet! I'm reading your book. Thank you for the answer and its example.

Comment: @Josell: Cracking - hopefully chapter 15 (or whichever one it is) might help :)